# Hand Coded State Driven Lexical Analyzer in C With Unit Test Part A

Tags: performance, c, unit-testing, cyclomatic-complexity, lexical-analysis

This code review is presented in 3 questions due to the amount of code:

1. Part A (this question) contains the Lexical Analyzer and the main portion of the unit test code.
2. [Part B](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248560/hand-coded-state-driven-lexical-analyzer-in-c-with-unit-test-part-b) contains the lower level unit tests called in Part A
3. [Part C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248561/hand-coded-state-driven-lexical-analyzer-in-c-with-unit-test-part-c) contains common unit test code that is included in all of the unit tests to be written.

### Background

Back in June I provided this [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244566/an-attempt-at-a-toy-vm/244573#244573) to a question here on code review. I advised the person that asked the question to use enums rather than numbers to represent the opcodes, but upon further consideration I thought that the virtual machine really needed an editor as the front end and I have been working on that. An editor will require a translator to convert text into the numbers the virtual machine uses for opcodes and operands. The translator is composed of a parser and a lexical analyzer. The lexical analyzer is complete, unit tested and debugged so I am presenting it here for code review with the unit tests.

This program is written in C because the original question was written in C. I tried to stick to the C90 standard as much as possible, but I did include _strdup() which is in the latest standard (perhaps it is strdup() in the latest standard, but Visual Studio suggested _strdup()).

### Why did I write unit tests for the lexical analyzer?

1. It is a best practice at many companies that do software development.
2. The code was very complex, at the time it was not a state machine (unit testing convinced me to go that route). It was over 450 lines of un-commented code in the parser module and growing.
3. I had gotten to the point where I wanted to test/debug the lexical analyzer and the parser wasn't working so I wanted a program that ran only the lexical analyzer.
4. I wanted to test/debug the code in a bottom up manner to make sure the lowest level functions were working correctly before testing the higher level functions.

The benefits of unit testing were that it forced me to create a more modular design and to redesign the lexical analyzer to use a state machine rather another method. The results are less code and a better working lexical analyzer. It will also force a redesign of the parser, but that is for another question.

### The Language

The language is fairly simple.

{OPCODE, OPERAND},
{OPCODE, OPERAND}

Here is a working program (it is the example program in the original question):

```
{PUSH, 0x0A},
{PUSH, 0x43},
{PUSH, 0x42},
{PUSH, 0x41},
{OUTPUTCHAR, 0x00},
{POP, 0x00},    
{OUTPUTCHAR, 0x00},
{POP, 0x00},
{OUTPUTCHAR, 0x00},
{POP, 0x00},
{HALT, 0x00}
```

[image]

### Questions

I learned C a long time ago from K&R “The C Programming Language” Version 1 (pre C89/C90).

1. Other than compiling this –O3 what can I do to optimize this code?
2. Are there any features in the more modern versions of C that could reduce the amount of code? There are currently more 1300 lines of commented code to test the 376 lines of commented code in lexical_analyzer.c and lexical_analyzer.h.
3. Is there archaic C usage that is not customary to use anymore?
4. Are the unit tests missing any test cases, especially edge cases?
5. Are there any memory leaks?
6. Is the code readable?
7. I don’t like the fact that I need to include the unit test files in lexical_analyzer.c do you see any way around this?
8. Is the language too complex?

### Code Available:

Rather than copy and pasting this code it is available in my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/pacmaninbw/VMWithEditor). The code as presented in these 3 questions is on the branch `Before_First_Code_Review`, updates including those based on the review will be added to the master branch. **Udate** The code reviews have been added to the appropriate [repository unit test directory](https://github.com/pacmaninbw/VMWithEditor/tree/Before_First_Code_Review/VMWithEditor/UnitTests/State_Machine_Unit_Test) in the `Before_First_Code_Review` branch.

The unit test ouput is always saved to a `.txt` file, a comparison text file is the [unit test folder](https://github.com/pacmaninbw/VMWithEditor/tree/master/VMWithEditor/UnitTests/State_Machine_Unit_Test/State_Machine_Unit_Test) in the repository. The unit test output is 1827 lines so it is not included here in the question.

There is a CMakeLists.txt file in the unit test directory, but I'm not sure it works so it isn't posted here. If anyone would like to test it, let me know what to do or how to fix it. I could give you permission to update it in GitHub.

[image: Layout of the Repository]

### The code being tested

**lexical_analyzer.h**

```
/*
 * lexical_analyzer.h
 *
 * The Syntax State Machine is a simple lexical analiser. Given the current syntax
 * state and the new input character what is the new syntax state. State machines
 * can be represented as tables. Table implementation of a state machine uses
 * more memory but performs faster, the lexical analyser programs Flex and LEX
 * generate tables to implement lexical analysis.
 *
 * This module uses enums to make the states and transitions easier to understand.
 *
 */
#ifndef SYNTAX_STATE_MACHINE_H
#define SYNTAX_STATE_MACHINE_H

typedef enum syntax_checks_list_items
{
    OPENBRACE = 0,
    CLOSEBRACE = 1,
    COMMA = 2,
    LEGALOPCODE = 3,
    LEGALOPERAND = 4,
    ILLEGALOPCODE = 5,
    ILLEGALOPERAND = 6,
    ILLEGALFIRSTCHAR = 7,
    MULTIPLESTATEMENTSONELINE = 8,
    ILLEGALCHAR = 9,
    MISSINGCOMMA = 10
#define SYNTAX_CHECK_COUNT 11
} Syntax_Check_List_Items;

typedef enum syntax_state_enum
{
    START_STATE = 0,                // Start of a new line, only white space or open brace is really expected
    ENTER_OPCODE_STATE = 1,         // Open brace encountered, waiting for opcode (first alpha character) white space or alpha is expected
    OPCODE_STATE = 2,               // Open brace and first leter of opcode have been encoutered more alpha, white space or comma expected
    END_OPCODE_STATE = 3,           // White space has been encountered only white space or comma expected
    ENTER_OPERAND_STATE = 4,        // Comma has been encountered, waiting for first digit of operand white space allowed
    OPERAND_STATE = 5,              // First digit of operand has been encountered, remain in this state until white space or close brace is encountered.
    END_OPERAND_STATE = 6,          // White space has been encountered, waiting for close brace to end statement
    END_STATEMENT_STATE = 7,        // Close brace has been encountered, comma or new line expected
    DONE_STATE = 8,                 // Comma has been encountered only legal input is white space or new line
    ERROR_STATE = 9
} Syntax_State;

#define SYNTAX_STATE_ARRAY_SIZE    9 + 1    // (size_t) ERROR_STATE + 1

typedef enum legal_characters_that_cause_transitions
{
    OPENBRACE_STATE_TRANSITION = 0,        // This needs to be the same as OPENBRACE in Syntax_Check_List_Items
    CLOSEBRACE_STATE_TRANSITION = 1,       // This needs to be the same as CLOSEBRACE in Syntax_Check_List_Items
    COMMA_STATE_TRANSITION = 2,            // This needs to be the same as COMMA in Syntax_Check_List_Items
    ALPHA_STATE_TRANSITION = 3,
    DIGIT_STATE_TRANSITION = 4,
    WHITESPACE_STATE_TRANSITION = 5,
    EOL_STATE_TRANSITION = 6,              // End of Line
    ILLEGAL_CHAR_TRANSITION = 7
} State_Transition_Characters;
#define TRANSITION_ARRAY_SIZE 7 + 1        // ILLEGAL_CHAR_TRANSITION + 1

typedef struct syntax_state_transition
{
    Syntax_State current_state;
    Syntax_State transition_on_char_type[TRANSITION_ARRAY_SIZE];
} Syntax_State_Transition;

#define MAX_COMMA 2
#define MAX_OPEN_BRACE 1
#define MAX_CLOSE_BRACE 1
#define MAX_OPCODE 1
#define MAX_OPERAND 1
#define MAX_WHITE_SPACE    200

extern Syntax_State lexical_analyzer(Syntax_State current_state, unsigned char input, unsigned syntax_check_list[]);
extern void deactivate_lexical_analyzer(void);

#endif    //    SYNTAX_STATE_MACHINE_H
```

**lexical_analyzer.c**

```
/*
 * lexical_analyzer.c
 *
 * The Syntax State Machine is a simple lexical analyzer. Given the current syntax
 * state and the new input character what is the new syntax state. State machines
 * can be represented as tables. Table implementation of a state machine uses
 * more memory but performs faster, the lexical analyser programs Flex and LEX
 * generate tables to implement lexical analysis.
 *
 * This module uses enums to make the states and transitions easier to understand.
 *
 */
#include "lexical_analyzer.h"
#ifdef UNIT_TESTING
#include "common_unit_test_logic.h"
#else
#include "common_program_logic.h"
#endif
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 * This function returns the table that represents the current syntactic state
 * and the new state that each possible legal into can go to from the current
 * state. If this function is successful the function deallocate_next_states()
 * should be called when the lexical analisys is done.
 *
 * To allow the parser to report as many errors as possible per statement
 * not all errors result in ERROR_STATE, missing required items are reported
 * in a separate data structure. The decision to report the error is made
 * at the parser level.
 *
 * Columns in table below
 *    OPENBRACE_STATE_TRANSITION = 0,
 *    CLOSEBRACE_STATE_TRANSITION = 1,
 *    COMMA_STATE_TRANSITION = 2,
 *    ALPHA_STATE_TRANSITION = 3,
 *    DIGIT_STATE_TRANSITION = 4,
 *    WHITESPACE_STATE_TRANSITION = 5,
 *    EOL_STATE_TRANSITION = 6        // End of Line
 *  ILLEGAL_CHAR_TRANSITION = 7
 *
 * Rows in table below
 *    START_STATE = 0,            Start of a new line, only white space or open brace is really expected
 *    ENTER_OPCODE_STATE = 1,     Open brace encountered, waiting for opcode (first alpha character) white space or alpha is expected
 *    OPCODE_STATE = 2,           Open brace and first leter of opcode have been encoutered more alpha, white space or comma expected
 *    END_OPCODE_STATE = 3,       White space has been encountered only white space or comma expected
 *    ENTER_OPERAND_STATE = 4,    Comma has been encountered, waiting for first digit of operand white space allowed
 *    OPERAND_STATE = 5,          First digit of operand has been encountered, remain in this state until white space or close brace is encountered.
 *    END_OPERAND_STATE = 6,      White space has been encountered, waiting for close brace to end statement
 *    END_STATEMENT_STATE = 7,    Close brace has been encountered, comma or new line expected
 *    DONE_STATE = 8,             Comma has been encountered only legal input is white space or new line
 *    ERROR_STATE = 9
 */
static Syntax_State_Transition* allocate_next_states_once = NULL;
static Syntax_State_Transition* get_or_create_next_states(void)
{
    if (allocate_next_states_once)
    {
        return allocate_next_states_once;
    }

    allocate_next_states_once = calloc(((size_t)ERROR_STATE) + 1, sizeof(*allocate_next_states_once));
    if (!allocate_next_states_once)
    {
        report_error_generic("In create_next_states(), memory allocation for next_states failed\n");
        return allocate_next_states_once;
    }

    allocate_next_states_once[START_STATE] = (Syntax_State_Transition){ START_STATE, {ENTER_OPCODE_STATE, ERROR_STATE,
        ENTER_OPERAND_STATE, OPCODE_STATE, OPERAND_STATE, START_STATE, DONE_STATE, ERROR_STATE} };
    allocate_next_states_once[ENTER_OPCODE_STATE] = (Syntax_State_Transition){ ENTER_OPCODE_STATE, {ENTER_OPCODE_STATE,
        END_STATEMENT_STATE, ENTER_OPERAND_STATE, OPCODE_STATE, OPERAND_STATE, ENTER_OPCODE_STATE,
        ERROR_STATE, ERROR_STATE} };
    allocate_next_states_once[OPCODE_STATE] = (Syntax_State_Transition){OPCODE_STATE, {ERROR_STATE, END_STATEMENT_STATE,
        ENTER_OPERAND_STATE, OPCODE_STATE, OPERAND_STATE, END_OPCODE_STATE, ERROR_STATE, ERROR_STATE} };
    allocate_next_states_once[END_OPCODE_STATE] = (Syntax_State_Transition){ END_OPCODE_STATE, {ERROR_STATE,
        END_STATEMENT_STATE, ENTER_OPERAND_STATE, ERROR_STATE, OPERAND_STATE, END_OPCODE_STATE,
        ERROR_STATE, ERROR_STATE} };
    allocate_next_states_once[ENTER_OPERAND_STATE] = (Syntax_State_Transition){ ENTER_OPERAND_STATE, {ERROR_STATE,
        END_STATEMENT_STATE, DONE_STATE, ERROR_STATE, OPERAND_STATE, ENTER_OPERAND_STATE, ERROR_STATE} };
    allocate_next_states_once[OPERAND_STATE] = (Syntax_State_Transition){ OPERAND_STATE, {ERROR_STATE, END_STATEMENT_STATE,
        DONE_STATE, ERROR_STATE, OPERAND_STATE, END_OPERAND_STATE, ERROR_STATE, ERROR_STATE} };
    allocate_next_states_once[END_OPERAND_STATE] = (Syntax_State_Transition){ END_OPERAND_STATE, {ERROR_STATE,
        END_STATEMENT_STATE, DONE_STATE, ERROR_STATE, ERROR_STATE, END_OPERAND_STATE, ERROR_STATE, ERROR_STATE} };
    allocate_next_states_once[END_STATEMENT_STATE] = (Syntax_State_Transition){ END_STATEMENT_STATE, {ERROR_STATE,
        END_STATEMENT_STATE, DONE_STATE, ERROR_STATE, ERROR_STATE, END_STATEMENT_STATE, DONE_STATE, ERROR_STATE} };
    allocate_next_states_once[DONE_STATE] = (Syntax_State_Transition){ DONE_STATE, {ERROR_STATE, ERROR_STATE,
        DONE_STATE, ERROR_STATE, ERROR_STATE, DONE_STATE, DONE_STATE, ERROR_STATE} };
    allocate_next_states_once[ERROR_STATE] = (Syntax_State_Transition){ ERROR_STATE, {ERROR_STATE, ERROR_STATE,
        ERROR_STATE, ERROR_STATE, ERROR_STATE, ERROR_STATE, ERROR_STATE, ERROR_STATE} };

    return allocate_next_states_once;
}

void deactivate_lexical_analyzer(void)
{
    free(allocate_next_states_once);
}

static bool is_legal_in_hex_number(unsigned char input)
{
    bool is_legal = false;

    switch (toupper(input))
    {
        case 'A':
        case 'B':
        case 'C':
        case 'D':
        case 'E':
        case 'F':
        case 'X':
            is_legal = true;
            break;

        default:
            is_legal = false;
            break;
    }


    return is_legal;
}

/*
 * The calling function has already gone through one filter so it is assured that
 * the input character is an alpha and not some other type of character.
 */
static State_Transition_Characters get_alpha_input_transition_character_type(unsigned char input, Syntax_State current_state)
{
    State_Transition_Characters character_type = ILLEGAL_CHAR_TRANSITION;

    switch (current_state)
    {
        case ENTER_OPERAND_STATE:
        case OPERAND_STATE:
        case END_OPERAND_STATE:
            character_type = (is_legal_in_hex_number(input)) ? DIGIT_STATE_TRANSITION :
                ALPHA_STATE_TRANSITION;
            break;

        default:
            character_type = ALPHA_STATE_TRANSITION;
            break;
    }

    return character_type;
}

/*
 * The calling function has already gone through several filter so it is assured
 * that the input character is not an alpha, digit, white space or end of line.
 */
static State_Transition_Characters get_puctuation_transition_character_type(unsigned char input)
{
    State_Transition_Characters character_type = ILLEGAL_CHAR_TRANSITION;

    switch (input)
    {
        case ',':
            character_type = COMMA_STATE_TRANSITION;
            break;

        case '{':
            character_type = OPENBRACE_STATE_TRANSITION;
            break;

        case '}':
            character_type = CLOSEBRACE_STATE_TRANSITION;
            break;

        default:
            character_type = ILLEGAL_CHAR_TRANSITION;
            break;
    }

    return character_type;
}

/*
 * The calling function has already gone through several filter so it is assured
 * that the input character is not an alpha, digit, white space or end of line.
 */
static State_Transition_Characters get_whitespace_transition_character_type(unsigned char input)
{
    State_Transition_Characters character_type = ILLEGAL_CHAR_TRANSITION;

    switch (input)
    {
        case ' ':
        case '\t':
            character_type = WHITESPACE_STATE_TRANSITION;
            break;

        case '\n':
        case '\r':
            character_type = EOL_STATE_TRANSITION;
            break;

        default:
            character_type = ILLEGAL_CHAR_TRANSITION;
            break;
    }

    return character_type;
}

/*
 * Rather than create a table indexed by each and every character in the character
 * set save space using ctype functions for large ranges. Also save time on
 * implementation and debugging.
 */
static State_Transition_Characters get_transition_character_type(unsigned char input, Syntax_State current_state)
{
    State_Transition_Characters character_type = ILLEGAL_CHAR_TRANSITION;
    if (isalpha(input))
    {
        character_type = get_alpha_input_transition_character_type(input, current_state);
    }
    else if (isdigit(input))
    {
        character_type = DIGIT_STATE_TRANSITION;
    }
    else if (isspace(input))
    {
        character_type = get_whitespace_transition_character_type(input);
    }
    else
    {
        character_type = get_puctuation_transition_character_type(input);
    }

    return character_type;
}

/*
 * syntax_check_list provides additional error information for the parser.
 */
static void collect_error_reporting_data(Syntax_State current_state,
    State_Transition_Characters character_type, unsigned syntax_check_list[])
{
    switch (character_type)
    {

        case WHITESPACE_STATE_TRANSITION:       // This section is for character types that
        case EOL_STATE_TRANSITION:              // are a legal first character on a line
            break;

        case COMMA_STATE_TRANSITION:            // Punctuation required by grammer on
        case OPENBRACE_STATE_TRANSITION:        // every line
        case CLOSEBRACE_STATE_TRANSITION:
        {
            unsigned maximum_allowed[] = { MAX_OPEN_BRACE, MAX_CLOSE_BRACE, MAX_COMMA };
            syntax_check_list[character_type]++;
            if (syntax_check_list[character_type] > maximum_allowed[character_type])
            {
                syntax_check_list[MULTIPLESTATEMENTSONELINE]++;
            }
        }    // flow through so that punctuation is handeled like all other character
        default:
            if (current_state == START_STATE && character_type != OPENBRACE_STATE_TRANSITION)
            {
                syntax_check_list[ILLEGALFIRSTCHAR]++;
            }
            break;
    }
}

/*
 * A design decision was made to allocate next_states only once to save overhead in
 * this function and to not force the parser to allocate the memory.
 * 
 * This function performs the lexical analysis for the parser, it uses a state machine
 * implemented as a table to do this. That table is the next_states variable.
 */
Syntax_State lexical_analyzer(Syntax_State current_state, unsigned char input, unsigned syntax_check_list[])
{
    Syntax_State_Transition* next_states = get_or_create_next_states();
    if (!next_states)
    {
        fprintf(error_out_file, "In %s: Memory allocation error in get_or_create_next_states()\n", "get_state_transition_collect_parser_error_data");
        fprintf(error_out_file, "Unable to perform lexical analisys! Exiting program.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    State_Transition_Characters character_type = get_transition_character_type(input, current_state);
    collect_error_reporting_data(current_state, character_type, syntax_check_list);

    return next_states[current_state].transition_on_char_type[character_type];
}

#ifdef UNIT_TESTING
#include "internal_sytax_state_tests.c"
#endif
```

### Unit Testing Code

**internal_sytax_state_tests.h**

```
#ifndef INTERNAL_SYNTAX_STATE_TEST_H
#define INTERNAL_SYNTAX_STATE_TEST_H

#include <stdbool.h>

extern bool internal_tests_on_all_state_transitions(unsigned test_step);
extern bool unit_test_lexical_analyzer(unsigned test_step);

#endif    // INTERNAL_SYNTAX_STATE_TEST_H
```

**internal_sytax_state_tests.c**

```
/* 
 * internal_sytax_state_tests.c
 *
 * This file contains both internal syntax state machine unit tests, and unit tests
 * for the public interface of the lexitcal analyzer these test functions test the
 * very basic functions that are the building blocks of the public interface, they are
 * declared static so these tests must be included in the syntax_state_machine.c file
 * rather than externally.
 */

#ifndef INTERNAL_SYNTAX_STATE_TESTS_C
#define INTERNAL_SYNTAX_STATE_TESTS_C

#include "internal_sytax_state_tests.h"
#include "lexical_analyzer_test_data.h"

static char *state_name_for_printing(Syntax_State state)
{
    char* state_names[SYNTAX_STATE_ARRAY_SIZE] =
    {
        "START_STATE",
        "ENTER_OPCODE_STATE",
        "OPCODE_STATE",
        "END_OPCODE_STATE",
        "ENTER_OPERAND_STATE",
        "OPERAND_STATE",
        "END_OPERAND_STATE",
        "END_STATEMENT_STATE",
        "DONE_STATE",
        "ERROR_STATE"
    };

    return state_names[(size_t)state];
}

static char* transition_character[TRANSITION_ARRAY_SIZE] =
{
    "Transition on {",
    "Transition on }",
    "Transition on ,",
    "Transition on Alpha",
    "Transition on Digit",
    "Transition on White Space",
    "Transition on EOL",
    "Transition on Illegal Character",
};

#ifdef UNIT_TEST_DEBUG
static bool unit_test_syntax_states(size_t test_step)
{
    bool test_passed = true;
    bool stand_alone = test_step == 0;

    Syntax_State_Transition* test_transitions = get_or_create_next_states();
    if (!test_transitions)
    {
        fprintf(error_out_file, "Memory allocation error in get_create_next_states()\n");
        return false;
    }

    for (size_t state = 0; state < SYNTAX_STATE_ARRAY_SIZE; state++)
    {
        char out_buffer[BUFSIZ];
        if (stand_alone)
        {
            sprintf(out_buffer, "current_state = %s\n", state_name_for_printing(
                test_transitions[state].current_state));
            log_generic_message(out_buffer);
        }

        if (stand_alone)
        {
            for (size_t character_index = 0; character_index < TRANSITION_ARRAY_SIZE;
                character_index++)
            {
                sprintf(out_buffer, "\ttransition character = %s\t\tnew state %s\n",
                    transition_character[character_index],
                    state_name_for_printing(
                        test_transitions[state].transition_on_char_type[character_index]));
                log_generic_message(out_buffer);
            }
            log_generic_message("\n");
        }
    }

    return test_passed;
}
#endif

#include "internal_character_transition_unit_tests.c"

typedef struct state_test_data
{
    Syntax_State current_state;
    State_Transition_Characters input_character_state;
    unsigned syntax_items_checklist[SYNTAX_CHECK_COUNT];
    Expected_Syntax_Errors expected_data;
} Error_Reporting_Test_Data;

static void print_syntax_error_checklist(unsigned syntax_checklist[], char *out_buffer)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < SYNTAX_CHECK_COUNT; i++)
    {
        char num_buff[8];
        if (i < SYNTAX_CHECK_COUNT - 1)
        {
            sprintf(num_buff, "%d ,", syntax_checklist[i]);
            strcat(out_buffer, num_buff);
        }
        else
        {
            sprintf(num_buff, "%d} ", syntax_checklist[i]);
            strcat(out_buffer, num_buff);
        }
    }
}
static void log_all_failure_data_for_unit_test_collect_error_reporting_data(
    Test_Log_Data* log_data, Error_Reporting_Test_Data test_data, unsigned syntax_check_list[])
{
    log_test_status_each_step2(log_data);

    char out_buffer[BUFSIZ];
    sprintf(out_buffer, "\tcurrent_state = %s ", state_name_for_printing(test_data.current_state));
    strcat(out_buffer, "expected Checklist Values {");
    print_syntax_error_checklist(test_data.expected_data.syntax_check_list, out_buffer);
    strcat(out_buffer, "new checklist value {");
    print_syntax_error_checklist(syntax_check_list, out_buffer);
    strcat(out_buffer, "\n");
    log_generic_message(out_buffer);
}

static bool errors_in_sync(unsigned syntax_check_list[], Expected_Syntax_Errors expected_errors)
{
    bool syntax_check_list_in_sync = true;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SYNTAX_CHECK_COUNT; i++)
    {
        if (syntax_check_list[i] != expected_errors.syntax_check_list[i])
        {
            syntax_check_list_in_sync = false;
        }
    }

    return syntax_check_list_in_sync;
}

static bool run_error_checking_unit_tests(
    Test_Log_Data *log_data, size_t positive_path_test_count,
    Error_Reporting_Test_Data test_data[], size_t test_runs)
{
    bool test_passed = true;

    log_start_test_path(log_data);

    for (size_t test_count = 0; test_count < test_runs; test_count++)
    {
        log_data->status = true;
        if (test_count == positive_path_test_count)
        {
            log_end_test_path(log_data);
            log_data->path = "Negative";
            log_start_test_path(log_data);
        }

        unsigned syntax_check_list[SYNTAX_CHECK_COUNT];
        memcpy(&syntax_check_list[0], &test_data[test_count].syntax_items_checklist[0], sizeof(syntax_check_list));

        collect_error_reporting_data(test_data[test_count].current_state,
            test_data[test_count].input_character_state, syntax_check_list);
        if (!errors_in_sync(syntax_check_list, test_data[test_count].expected_data))
        {
            log_data->status = false;
            log_all_failure_data_for_unit_test_collect_error_reporting_data(
                log_data, test_data[test_count], syntax_check_list);
        }
        else
        {
            log_test_status_each_step2(log_data);
        }

        if (!log_data->status && test_passed)
        {
            test_passed = log_data->status;
        }
    }

    log_end_test_path(log_data);

    return test_passed;
}

static Error_Reporting_Test_Data* init_error_report_data(size_t *positive_path_test_count, size_t *test_data_size)
{
    Error_Reporting_Test_Data static_global_test_data[] =
    {
        // Start with positive test path data
        {START_STATE, OPENBRACE_STATE_TRANSITION, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}},
        {OPERAND_STATE, CLOSEBRACE_STATE_TRANSITION, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}},
        {END_STATEMENT_STATE, COMMA_STATE_TRANSITION, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}},
        {OPCODE_STATE, COMMA_STATE_TRANSITION, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}},
        {END_OPCODE_STATE, COMMA_STATE_TRANSITION, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}},
        {END_OPCODE_STATE, WHITESPACE_STATE_TRANSITION, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}},
        {START_STATE, WHITESPACE_STATE_TRANSITION, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}},
        {OPERAND_STATE, WHITESPACE_STATE_TRANSITION, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}},
        {OPCODE_STATE, WHITESPACE_STATE_TRANSITION, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}},
        {END_OPCODE_STATE, EOL_STATE_TRANSITION, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}},
        {START_STATE, EOL_STATE_TRANSITION, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}},
        {OPERAND_STATE, EOL_STATE_TRANSITION, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}},
        {OPCODE_STATE, EOL_STATE_TRANSITION, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}},
        // Negative test path data
        {DONE_STATE, OPENBRACE_STATE_TRANSITION, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, {2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}}},
        {DONE_STATE, COMMA_STATE_TRANSITION,  {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, {0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}}},
        {DONE_STATE, CLOSEBRACE_STATE_TRANSITION, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}}},
    };
    *test_data_size = (sizeof(static_global_test_data) / sizeof(Error_Reporting_Test_Data));
    *positive_path_test_count = 13;        // Count the lines of test_data above between the comments above.

    Error_Reporting_Test_Data* test_data = calloc(*test_data_size, sizeof(*test_data));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < *test_data_size; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&test_data[i], &static_global_test_data[i], sizeof(*test_data));
    }

    return test_data;
}

static bool unit_test_collect_error_reporting_data(unsigned test_step)
{
    bool test_passed = true;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    Test_Log_Data* log_data = create_and_init_test_log_data(
        "unit_test_collect_error_reporting_data", test_passed, "Positive",
        test_step == 0);
    if (!log_data)
    {
        report_create_and_init_test_log_data_memory_failure(
            "unit_test_collect_error_reporting_data");
        return false;
    }

    size_t positivie_path_count = 0;
    size_t test_count = 0;
    Error_Reporting_Test_Data* test_data = init_error_report_data(&positivie_path_count, &test_count);
    if (!test_data)
    {
        fprintf(error_out_file, "Memory allocation of test_data failed in %s",
            log_data->function_name);
        return false;
    }

    if (log_data->stand_alone)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "STARTING internal unit test for %s()\n\n", "collect_error_reporting_data");
        log_generic_message(buffer);
    }

    test_passed = run_error_checking_unit_tests(log_data, positivie_path_count, test_data, test_count);

    if (log_data->stand_alone)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "\nENDING internal unit test for %s(\n\n", "collect_error_reporting_data");
        log_generic_message(buffer);
    }

    free(test_data);
    free(log_data);

    return test_passed;
}

typedef bool (*state_machine_unit_test_function)(size_t test_step);

typedef struct unit_test_functions_and_args
{
    char* test_name;
    state_machine_unit_test_function func;
} State_Machine_Unit_Test_Functions;

/*
 * This function unit tests all the internal functions that support the
 * function get_state_transition_collect_parser_error_data(). If any of
 * these unit tests fail the unit test for lexical_analyzer() will not
 * execute.
 */
bool internal_tests_on_all_state_transitions(unsigned test_step)
{
    bool all_tests_passed = true;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];

    State_Machine_Unit_Test_Functions unit_tests[] =
    {
#ifdef UNIT_TEST_DEBUG
        {"unit_test_syntax_states", unit_test_syntax_states},
#endif
        {"unit_test_get_alpha_input_transition_character_type",
            unit_test_get_alpha_input_transition_character_type},
        {"unit_test_get_transition_character_type",
            unit_test_get_transition_character_type},
        {"unit_test_collect_error_reporting_data",
            unit_test_collect_error_reporting_data},
    };
    size_t test_max = (sizeof(unit_tests) / sizeof(*unit_tests));

    for (size_t test_count = 0; test_count < test_max; test_count++)
    {
        bool test_passed = unit_tests[test_count].func(test_step);
        sprintf(buffer, "\nSyntax Machine Internal Unit Test %zd: %s : %s\n\n",
            test_count + 1, unit_tests[test_count].test_name,
            (test_passed) ? "Passed" : "Failed");
        log_generic_message(buffer);
        // if one test already failed we are good
        if (all_tests_passed)
        {
            all_tests_passed = test_passed;
        }
    }    

    return all_tests_passed;
}

static void report_syntax_errors(unsigned necessary_items[])
{
    char* error_strings[SYNTAX_CHECK_COUNT];
    error_strings[OPENBRACE] = "Missing the opening brace.";
    error_strings[CLOSEBRACE] = "Missing the closing brace.";
    error_strings[COMMA] = "Missing comma(s)";
    error_strings[LEGALOPCODE] = "Missing or unknow opcode";
    error_strings[LEGALOPERAND] = "Missing operand or operand out of range";
    error_strings[ILLEGALOPCODE] = "Unknown Opcode.";
    error_strings[ILLEGALFIRSTCHAR] = "Illegal character in column 1 (are you missing the opening brace { )";
    error_strings[MULTIPLESTATEMENTSONELINE] = "Only one program step per line";
    error_strings[ILLEGALCHAR] = "Illegal Character";
    error_strings[MISSINGCOMMA] = "Missing comma(s)";

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SYNTAX_CHECK_COUNT; i++)
    {
        char buffer[BUFSIZ];
        if (i >= ILLEGALOPCODE && necessary_items[i])
        {
            sprintf(buffer, "\t%s\n", error_strings[i]);
            log_generic_message(buffer);
        }
        else if (i < ILLEGALOPCODE && !necessary_items[i])
        {
            sprintf(buffer, "\t%s\n", error_strings[i]);
            log_generic_message(buffer);
        }
    }

}

static bool check_syntax_check_list_and_report_errors_as_parser_would(
    unsigned syntax_check_list[], Syntax_State state, unsigned char* text_line,
    size_t statement_number, Expected_Syntax_Errors* expected_errors,
    char *parser_generated_error)
{
    unsigned error_count = 0;
    bool syntax_check_list_in_sync = true;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SYNTAX_CHECK_COUNT; i++)
    {
        error_count += (!syntax_check_list[i] && i < ILLEGALOPCODE) ? 1 : ((i >= ILLEGALOPCODE && syntax_check_list[i]) ? 1 : 0);
        if (syntax_check_list[i] != expected_errors->syntax_check_list[i] && i != MULTIPLESTATEMENTSONELINE)
        {
            syntax_check_list_in_sync = false;
        }
    }

    if (error_count != expected_errors->error_count)
    {
        syntax_check_list_in_sync = false;
    }

    char* eol_p = strrchr((const char *)text_line, '\n');
    if (eol_p)
    {
        *eol_p = '\0';
    }
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    if (state == ERROR_STATE || error_count)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "\n\nStatement %d (%s) has the following syntax errors\n", statement_number + 1, text_line);
        log_generic_message(buffer);
        if (parser_generated_error)
        {
            log_generic_message(parser_generated_error);
        }
        report_syntax_errors(syntax_check_list);
    }
    else
    {
        if (expected_errors->error_count)
        {
            sprintf(buffer, "\n\nStatement %d (%s)\n", statement_number + 1, text_line);
            log_generic_message(buffer);
            sprintf(buffer, "Expected syntax errors were:\n");
            log_generic_message(buffer);
            report_syntax_errors(expected_errors->syntax_check_list);
        }
    }

    return syntax_check_list_in_sync;
}

static char* error_state(unsigned char* text_line, size_t statement_number, unsigned char* current_character)
{
    char* parser_generated_error;

    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    char* eol_p = strrchr((const char*)text_line, '\n');
    if (eol_p)
    {
        *eol_p = '\0';
    }
    sprintf(buffer,
        "Syntax Error line %zd %s column %d unexpected character '%c' : skipping rest of line.\n",
        statement_number + 1, text_line, (int)(current_character - text_line),
        *current_character);
    parser_generated_error = _strdup(buffer);

    return parser_generated_error;
}

/*
 * Provides debug data when a unit test fails.
 */
static void report_lexical_analyzer_test_failure(Syntax_State current_state, unsigned syntax_check_list[], Expected_Syntax_Errors* expected_errors)
{
    char out_buffer[BUFSIZ];
    sprintf(out_buffer, "\tcurrent_state = %s expected error count = %d ",
        state_name_for_printing(current_state), expected_errors->error_count);
    strcat(out_buffer, "expected Checklist Values {");
    print_syntax_error_checklist(expected_errors->syntax_check_list, out_buffer);
    strcat(out_buffer, "new checklist values {");
    print_syntax_error_checklist(syntax_check_list, out_buffer);
    strcat(out_buffer, "\n");
    log_generic_message(out_buffer);
}

/*
 * This test parses a signle statement as the parser would. It directly calls
 * the lexical analiyzer for each character.
 */
static bool unit_test_final_lexical_parse_statement(unsigned char* text_line, size_t statement_number, Test_Log_Data* log_data, Expected_Syntax_Errors *expected_errors)
{
    bool test_passed = true;

    unsigned syntax_check_list[SYNTAX_CHECK_COUNT];
    memset(&syntax_check_list[0], 0, sizeof(syntax_check_list));
    Syntax_State current_state = START_STATE;
    unsigned char* opcode_start = NULL;
    unsigned char* opcode_end = NULL;
    unsigned char* operand_start = NULL;
    char* parser_generated_error = NULL;

    unsigned char* current_character = text_line;
    while (*current_character && current_state != ERROR_STATE)
    {
        Syntax_State new_state = lexical_analyzer(current_state, *current_character, syntax_check_list);
        if (new_state != current_state)
        {
            switch (new_state)
            {
                case ERROR_STATE:
                {
                    parser_generated_error = error_state(text_line, statement_number, current_character);
                };
                    break;

                case OPCODE_STATE:
                    opcode_start = current_character;
                    syntax_check_list[LEGALOPCODE]++;
                    break;

                case END_OPCODE_STATE:
                    opcode_end = current_character;
                    break;

                case OPERAND_STATE:
                    operand_start = current_character;
                    syntax_check_list[LEGALOPERAND]++;
                    if (!syntax_check_list[COMMA])
                    {
                        syntax_check_list[MISSINGCOMMA]++;
                    }
                    break;

                case END_OPERAND_STATE:
                    opcode_end = current_character;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            current_state = new_state;
        }

        current_character++;
    }

    bool syntax_check_list_in_sync = check_syntax_check_list_and_report_errors_as_parser_would(
        syntax_check_list, current_state, text_line, statement_number, expected_errors, parser_generated_error);

    if (!syntax_check_list_in_sync)
    {
        report_lexical_analyzer_test_failure(current_state, syntax_check_list, expected_errors);
        test_passed = false;
        log_data->status = false;
    }

    log_test_status_each_step2(log_data);
    free(parser_generated_error);

    return test_passed;
}

bool run_parse_program_loop(Test_Log_Data* log_data, Lexical_Analyzer_Test_Data* test_data)
{
    bool test_passed = true;

    unsigned char** test_program = test_data->test_program;
    Expected_Syntax_Errors* expected_errors = test_data->expected_errors;

    for (size_t test_count = 0; test_count < test_data->test_program_size; test_count++)
    {
        log_data->status = true;
        if (!unit_test_final_lexical_parse_statement(test_program[test_count], test_count,
            log_data, &expected_errors[test_count]))
        {
            test_passed = log_data->status;
        }
    }

    return test_passed;
}
/*
 * This final test imitates the parser and parses an entire program. There are
 * 2 programs, one without syntax errors and one with syntax errors. The positive
 * test path is the one without syntax errors and the negative path is the one
 * with syntax errors.
 */
bool unit_test_parse_statements_for_lexical_analysis(unsigned test_step)
{
    bool test_passed = true;
    Test_Log_Data* log_data = create_and_init_test_log_data(
        "unit_test_parse_statements_for_lexical_analysis", test_passed, "Positive",
        test_step == 0);

    Lexical_Analyzer_Test_Data* positive_path_data = init_positive_path_data_for_lexical_analysis(log_data);
    if (!positive_path_data)
    {
        return false;
    }

    log_start_test_path(log_data);
    if (!run_parse_program_loop(log_data, positive_path_data))
    {
        test_passed = log_data->status;
    }
    log_end_test_path(log_data);


    Lexical_Analyzer_Test_Data* negative_path_data = init_negative_path_data_for_lexical_analysis(log_data);
    if (!negative_path_data)
    {
        return false;
    }

    log_data->path = "Negative";
    log_start_test_path(log_data);
    char* explanation = "Only statements with syntax errors are printed"
        " Statement 1 and statement 8 do not contain syntax errors\n\n";
    log_generic_message(explanation);
    if (!run_parse_program_loop(log_data, negative_path_data))
    {
        test_passed = log_data->status;
    }
    log_end_test_path(log_data);

    deallocate_lexical_test_data(positive_path_data);
    deallocate_lexical_test_data(negative_path_data);
    free(log_data);

    return test_passed;
}

/* 
 * Unit test the public interface in syntax_state_machine.c. This function
 * assumes that internal_tests_on_all_state_transitions has been previously
 * called and that all component functions have been unit tested first. The 
 * public interface is tested in 2 ways, first with test data and then
 * parsing statements as the parser will.
 */
bool unit_test_lexical_analyzer(unsigned test_step)
{
    bool test_passed = true;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];

    Test_Log_Data* log_data = create_and_init_test_log_data(
        "unit_test_lexical_analyzer", test_passed, "Positive",
        test_step == 0);
    if (!log_data)
    {
        report_create_and_init_test_log_data_memory_failure("unit_test_lexical_analyzer");
        return false;
    }

    if (log_data->stand_alone)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "STARTING unit test for %s\n\n", log_data->function_name);
        log_generic_message(buffer);
    }

    test_passed = unit_test_parse_statements_for_lexical_analysis(test_step);

    if (log_data->stand_alone)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "\nENDING unit test for %s\n\n", log_data->function_name);
        log_generic_message(buffer);
    }

    free(log_data);

    return test_passed;
}
#endif    // INTERNAL_SYNTAX_STATE_TESTS_C
```

**state_machine_unit_test_main.h**

```
#ifndef SYNTAX_STATE_MACHINE_UNIT_TEST_MAIN_H
#define SYNTAX_STATE_MACHINE_UNIT_TEST_MAIN_H

extern bool run_all_syntax_state_machine_unit_tests(unsigned test_step);

#endif    // SYNTAX_STATE_MACHINE_UNIT_TEST_MAIN_H
```

Since this program is designed to be part of larger unit tests `main()` is contained within ifdef/endif. It will only be compiled if this is a stand alone test.

**state_machine_unit_test_main.c**

```
// state_machine_unit_test.c : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
#include "common_unit_test_logic.h"
#include "lexical_analyzer.h"
#include "internal_sytax_state_tests.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool run_all_syntax_state_machine_unit_tests(unsigned test_step)
{
    bool all_unit_tests_passed = true;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];

    sprintf(buffer, "Unit Test %zd: Starting Lexical Analizer Unit Tests \n\n", test_step);
    log_generic_message(buffer);

    all_unit_tests_passed = internal_tests_on_all_state_transitions(test_step);

    if (all_unit_tests_passed)
    {
        // test the public interface for the lexical analyzer
        all_unit_tests_passed = 
            unit_test_lexical_analyzer(test_step);
    }

    sprintf(buffer, "Unit Test %zd: run_all_syntax_state_machine_unit_tests(unsigned "
        "test_step) : %s\n\n", test_step, all_unit_tests_passed ? "Passed" : "Failed");
    log_generic_message(buffer);

    deactivate_lexical_analyzer();

    sprintf(buffer, "Unit Test %zd: Ending Lexical Analizer Unit Tests \n\n", test_step);
    log_generic_message(buffer);

    return all_unit_tests_passed;
}

#ifdef LEXICAL_UNIT_TEST_ONLY
int main()
{
    error_out_file = stderr;
    int passed = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    if (!init_vm_error_reporting(NULL) ||
        !init_unit_tests("syntax_state_machine_unit_test_log.txt"))
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!run_all_syntax_state_machine_unit_tests(0))
    {
        passed = EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    close_unit_tests();
    disengage_error_reporting();

    return passed;
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"%z..."`

Avoid UB.

Codes use [`"%zd"`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32916575/2410359) with `size_t` and `unsigned`.

Use `"%zu"` with `size_t` and `"%u"` with `unsigned`.

**Name space**

(Is the code readable?) `lexical_analyzer.h` introduces types and macros such as `SYNTAX_STATE_MACHINE_H`, `COMMA`, `State_Transition_Characters`, `MAX_OPCODE`, in a inconsistent manner.

Name collision avoidance is difficult as naming covers too many naming styles.

Consider a common prefix for all, perhaps `lapac_` in `lapac.h`.

**Take care with failed data**

Avoid UB. `report_lexical_analyzer_test_failure()`

When things fail, avoid assuming too much about *string* data.

I recommend printing *string* with sentinels such as `"<"`, `">"` for clarity as to the start/end of a string which may include *white space*..

Take better string length care by using `snprintf()`, etc., than hoping `char out_buffer[BUFSIZ];` is big enough.

**Simplify verbose code**

(Are there any features in the more modern versions of C that could reduce the amount of code?)

```
// Instead of 22 line original, avoid locale dependencies and shorten.
static bool is_legal_in_hex_number(unsigned char input) {
  return (isxdigit(input) && !isdigit(input)) || (input == 'x' || input == 'X');
}
```

It is unclear to me why original `is_legal_in_hex_number(some_0_to_9_digit)` returns `false`.

**Minor**

`state_machine_unit_test_main.h` should include `<stdbool.h>`

`()` around macro equations..

```
// #define SYNTAX_STATE_ARRAY_SIZE    9 + 1
#define SYNTAX_STATE_ARRAY_SIZE    (9 + 1)
```

Comment: `SYNTAX_STATE_MACHINE_H` is a problem, the `lexical_analyzer.*` files were originally named `syntax_state_machine.*` and I missed changing that macro when I changed the file name (the file name changes might be documented in the git change history, it was in the commit message). The enum COMMA is in the same set of enums as OPENBRACE, and CLOSEBRACE, what would you suggest for COMMA instead? Thank you for the review, I know it took lots of time. I see your point about `is_legal_in_hex_number()`, however I don't think opcodes will ever contain digit's, I should add that to the documentation.

Comment: I didn't know about `isxdigit()` thank you!

Comment: @pacmaninbw Pedantic detail about `isxdigit()` vs `switch(toupper(ch)) case 'A' ... case 'F': ...`.  `isxdigit()` true for 10+6+6 characters - independent of locale..  `toupper(AE_with_a_diacritical_mark)` might map to `A` or `E` depending on locale.  C's _locale_ features impose corner issues.

Comment: @pacmaninbw "what would you suggest for COMMA instead?" -->Example: I like the model of a `asdf.h` only declaring functions, vars, defines, types, macros,  etc. all beginning with `asdf_` or macros with `ASDF_` or a type `asdf`.  I tend to code like that even with `enum`s.  I find that approach easier to maintain.

Comment: The review has been copied into an md file and posted to the [repository](https://github.com/pacmaninbw/VMWithEditor/tree/Before_First_Code_Review/VMWithEditor/UnitTests/State_Machine_Unit_Test/State_Machine_Unit_Test). In the md file there is a link back to this answer. Both of your answers are there.

Answer (score 2):

## Answers to your questions

> I learned C a long time ago from K&R “The C Programming Language” Version 1 (pre C89/C90).

I started with K&R C's second revision, but that doesn't mean I didn't keep up with the changes over time. C99 brought many useful improvements that I happily use every day. Your code looks C99 as well, since you are using `bool` and `//` comments.

> 1. Other than compiling this `–O3` what can I do to optimize this code?

Try to do as much as possible at compile time instead of run time. For example, instead of having `get_or_create_next_states()`, it seems to me you can create a static array, like so:

```
static Syntax_State_Transition next_states[] = {
    [START_STATE] = {START_STATE, {ENTER_OPCODE_STATE, ERROR_STATE, ENTER_OPERAND_STATE, OPCODE_STATE, OPERAND_STATE, START_STATE, DONE_STATE, ERROR_STATE}},
    [ENTER_OPCODE_STATE] = {...},
    ...
};
```

The above uses C99 designated initializers. If you don't want to use C99, you can omit the designations, but then you have to remember the correct order.

> 2. Are there any features in the more modern versions of C that could reduce the amount of code? There are currently more 1300 lines of commented code to test the 376 lines of commented code in lexical_analyzer.c and lexical_analyzer.h.

There are a some things that could reduce a few lines of code. For example, when logging messages, you write:

```
sprintf(buffer, "\nSome message, %s\n\n", some_variable);
log_generic_message(buffer);
```

Apart from `sprintf()` being unsafe, you can make `log_generic_message()` a [variadic function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) that takes a format strings and a variable number of arguments, like so:

```
void log_generic_message(const char *format, ...)
{
    char buffer[...];
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, format);
    vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, format, args);
    va_end(args);

    ...
}
```

This way, you can just write:

```
log_generic_message("\nSome message, %s\n\n", some_variable);
```

You can also use [`__attribute__((format(...)))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-format-function-attribute) to tell the compiler that you expect a `printf`-like format string, and it can then give the same warnings it will give if you have mismatching conversion specifiers and arguments. Of course support for function attributes might vary between compilers and cannot be used portably, unless you add some checks for it and `#ifdef` it out when the compiler doesn't support it.

There's a `memset()` that can be replaced using an array initializer:

```
unsigned syntax_check_list[SYNTAX_CHECK_COUNT];
memset(&syntax_check_list[0], 0, sizeof(syntax_check_list));
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
unsigned syntax_check_list[SYNTAX_CHECK_COUNT] = {0};
```

> 3. Is there archaic C usage that is not customary to use anymore?

Not that I see.

> 4. Are the unit tests missing any test cases, especially edge cases?

I'm not sure.

> 5. Are there any memory leaks?

Not that I see.

> 6. Is the code readable?

Well, mostly. But I would personally have used a lexer generator like [flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser), so I can write the lexer in a higher level language, and not have to deal with writing the code myself. Even though the language you are implementing is very simple, the lexer you wrote is already quite large, and if the language would get more complex, your lexer will quickly become unmaintainable, I'm afraid.

> 7. I don’t like the fact that I need to include the unit test files in lexical_analyzer.c do you see any way around this?

Yes, do it the other way around: in `internal_sytax_state_tests.c`, add `#include "lexical_analyzer.c"`. Alternatively, if you don't want to `#include` .c files into each other, then you have to find some way to remove the `static` from functions that you want to be able to unit test. A typical way to do that is:

```
#ifdef UNIT_TESTING
#define STATIC
#else
#define STATIC static
#endif

...

STATIC bool is_legal_in_hex_number(unsigned char input) {
    ...
}
```

Then when building the unit test, you can link the unit testing code with a version of `lexical_analyzer.c` built with `UNIT_TESTING` defined.

> 8. Is the language too complex?

The language is not complex at all, but as you see you already had to write a lot of code to parse it. That's why lexer and parser generators have been created.

## Use of `_strdup()`

The function `strdup()` is not in any C standard, but it is in POSIX.1-2001. As mentioned by @chux-ReinstateMonica, the C standard reserves identifiers starting with `str`, so Microsoft decided to not violate that rule and declare `_strdup()` instead. What I typically do in my own projects that need to be compatible with a certain standard, and where I want to use some commonly available convenience function that is not present in the standards I can safely use in my projects, is to add some check for the presence of the desired function, and if it's not present, either add an alias to a similar function or just write a drop-in replacement. So for example, you could write:

```
#ifndef HAVE_STRDUP
#ifdef HAVE__STRDUP
#define strdup(x) _strdup(x)
#else
static char *strdup(const char *x) {
    size_t len = strlen(x) + 1;
    char *s = malloc(len);
    if (s)
        memcpy(s, x, len);
    return s;
}
#endif
```

Then either have a build tool like autoconf figure out which functions are available and `#define HAVE_...` somewhere, or replace `#ifdef HAVE_STRDUP` by some other way to check for the availability of that function.

Comment: Thank you for the review. While I haven't used Bison and Flex I have used YACC and Lex (a lot actually). When I started this I wasn't even using a state driven array, I didn't think it was going to be that difficult. I don't see how including lexical_analyzer.c in the unit test is any different than the other way around other than it removes the` #ifdef UNIT_TESTING` from lexical_analyzer.c.

Comment: " don't know why they felt the need to create a version with an underscore in front" --> exactly to allow conditional code like `#define strdup(x) _strdup(x)`  [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7582741/2410359).  Had they unconditional supplied `strdup()` it would have been non-compliant  with C as it collides with reserved name space.  In this case, MS is following the standard.

Comment: " If you don't want to use C99" --> Note: Lots of re-work then changing `//` into `/*  */`.

Comment: @pacmaninbw So what you really don't like is `#include`ing .c files? If you want to avoid that, but still want to unit test `static` functions, then you need to do something like `#ifdef UNIT_TESTING #define STATIC #else #define STATIC static #endif`, and replace all `static` with `STATIC` in lexical_analyzer.c Then you can just link the latter with your unit testing .c files.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ah, I did not know about C reserving identifiers starting with `str`. I think that rule is violated a lot.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Detail: Its a lib thing under "Future library directions": "7.31.13 String handling <string.h> 1 Function names that begin with str, mem, or wcs and a lowercase letter may be added to the declarations in the <string.h> header."

Comment: The review has been copied into an md file and posted to the [repository](https://github.com/pacmaninbw/VMWithEditor/tree/Before_First_Code_Review/VMWithEditor/UnitTests/State_Machine_Unit_Test/State_Machine_Unit_Test). In the md file there is a link back to this answer.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I have linked to this answer from the [follow up question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248817/common-unit-testing-code-follow-up/248883#248883). I implemented your suggestion about including the module being tested rather than the test modules, I replaced the usage of `sprintf()` mostly with 2 variadic functions but also with `snprintf()`. The updated code is in the [repository](https://github.com/pacmaninbw/VMWithEditor/tree/master/VMWithEditor).