# Product of all but one number in a sequence

Tags: c, array, interview-questions

I was given the following prompt in a coding interview:

> Given an array of integers, return a new array such that each element at index i of the new array is the product of all the numbers in the original array except the one at i.
>
> For example, if our input was [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], the expected output would be [120, 60, 40, 30, 24]

I solved this in two ways:

- `fun` multiplies all elements together in the first iteration, and then loops again and divides by the number at that position
- `fun2` does not use division, and instead iteratively builds up the sum in each index

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fun(int* nums, int arr_size)
{
    int sum;
    int i;
    
    for(i=0, sum=1; i<arr_size; i++)
        sum*=nums[i];
    for(i=0; i<arr_size; i++)
        nums[i]=sum/nums[i];
    return 0;
}

int fun2(int* nums, int arr_size)
{
    int i,j;
    int sum=1;
    int new_arr[arr_size];
  
    for(i=0; i<arr_size; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<arr_size; j++) {
            if(i!=j)
                sum*=nums[j]; //skip member same index in the loop
        }
        new_arr[i]=sum;
        sum=1; 
    }
    memcpy(nums, new_arr, arr_size*sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    /*Given an array of integers, return a new array such that each element at index i of the 
    new array is the product of all the numbers in the original array except the one at i.
    For example, if our input was [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], the expected output would be 
    [120, 60, 40, 30, 24] */
    int nums[] = {1, 2, 2, 4, 6};    
    int size = sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]);
    int i;
    fun(nums, size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        printf("%d ", nums[i]); 
    
    //what if you can't use division?
    printf("\n");
    int nums2[] = {1, 2, 2, 4, 6}; 
    fun2(nums2, size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        printf("%d ", nums2[i]);
   
    return 0;
}
```
````

Comment: It feels like this might have a mathematical solution that gives better time complexity then O(N²) for `fun2` but I am not good enough at math to find it, so my only nit pick for `fun2` is that you don't need the `sum` var. Just use `new_arr[i]` directly. Also, I would suggest moving the description of what the code does from comment in `main` to actual text of you question above the code to make it easy for other users find it. It is easy to miss and people might ignore the question if they don't know what the code is suppose to produce.

Comment: Please make up your mind. Is it about **sum** or about **product**?

Comment: You're supposed to "return a new array" but your first solution doesn't even create one and the second solution doesn't return it.

Comment: Your first code fails if there's a zero.

Comment: @superbrain both solutions return an array in the original array passed in, the problem with it is the original data is destroyed.

Comment: @LevM.At a cost of additional array you can reduce the `fun2` complexity to O(N). Just sweep the input up and down to calculate a running product of the input array's prefixes and the input array's suffixes. Then multiply them to get `result[i] = prefixproduct[i-1] * suffixproduct[i+1]` (with a necessary special handling of two edge cases).

Comment: @pacmaninbw I'd say calling that "*returning* a *new* array" is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @CiaPan there’s a way to do this without requiring an array beyond the returned one.

Comment: @Edward You're right, one array suffices.

Comment: @Edward, CiaPan Thanks for the hint. I will implement new function and add it to this thread.

Comment: @CiaPan new code here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/251929/product-of-all-but-one-number-in-a-sequence-follow-up

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Use all required `#include`s

The code uses `memcpy`, so it should `#include <string.h>`.  It might still compile on your machine, with your compiler, but it's not portable.

### Think about potential errors

As one of the comments correctly notes, if one of the entries has the value of zero, this line will have a problem:

```
nums[i]=sum/nums[i];
```

Also, what happens if the passed `arr_size` is zero or negative?  What should the function return if there is exactly one item in the array? What if the passed pointer is `NULL`?

### Follow directions exactly

The problem says to "return a new array" but that is not really what this code is doing.  This code is overwriting the input array.  One of the problems with that is that it's not possible to call this with a `const` pointer as mentioned in the next suggestion.  It also means that rather than returning a meaningless constant value in all cases, the function should probably return a pointer.

### Use `const` where practical

As mentioned above, the code should return a new array rather than overwriting the passed one.  I would suggest that the function should be something like this:

```
int* exclusive_product(const int* nums, size_t nums_size)
```

Note that first, we use `const` and second, we use `size_t` rather than `int` for the second argument to more clearly indicate the type of variable we are expecting.

### Use better variable names

I would say that `nums`, `size` and `i` are good variable names, but that `fun` and `fun2` and definitely `sum` are not.  The problem is that `fun` doesn't tell the reader anything about what the code is supposed to do and `sum` is actually misleading (it's a *product*, not a *sum*).

### Think about an efficient way to solve this

The \$O(n^2)\$ code you have in `fun2` is not a terrible way to solve the problem and has the advantage of being obviously correct.  When I interview people, I typically like such answers because it's much easier to make slow *correct* code fast than it is to make fast *incorrect* code correct.  However, in a good interview, I like to ask the candidate to make comments on his or her own code, including any limitations, assumptions or potential improvements that might be made.  In this case, it helps if we think mathematically about the final values in the resulting array \$B\$ from input array \$A\$.  For example, we know that every value \$B_j\$ can be expressed as the product $$\displaystyle B_j = \prod_{i=0}^{j-1} A_i \prod_{i=j+1}^{n-1} A_i$$ if \$n\$ is the length of the array.  This suggests a more efficient approach I'll leave for you to figure out.

Comment: You ask what happens when `arr_size` is zero. Pretty much *nothing* happens, right? Which is the right thing.

Comment: @superbrain: My point in including that question (and others) it is to get the person *writing* the program to think about and answer the question.  If they can answer, with confidence, what it does in those corner cases, then they've thought about it, which is the kind of thing one would want to demonstrate in a job interview.

Comment: Another issue with division is that now you're working in floating point math.

Comment: @Acccumulation The original code did not use floating point division.

Comment: @Edward please take look at my new code here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/251929/product-of-all-but-one-number-in-a-sequence-follow-up

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by a commenter on the question, neither version satisfies the requirement to **return a new array**.  I'll leave that for you to fix yourself (demonstrating your understanding of memory allocation to your interviewer).

The division version requires some modification to work when one or more inputs are zero.  I suggest keeping track of the position of any zero that is found on the first pass - if a second zero is found, all the results will be zero, and if a single zero is found, then all the results except at that position will be zero.

That looks a bit like this:

```
void fun(int *nums, int arr_size)
{
    int product = 1;
    int zero_pos = -1;

    for (int i = 0;  i < arr_size;  i++) {
        if (nums[i]) {
            product *= nums[i];
        } else if (zero_pos < 0) {
            zero_pos = i;
        } else {
            product = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (zero_pos < 0) {
        for(int i = 0;  i < arr_size;  i++) {
            nums[i] = product / nums[i];
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0;  i < arr_size;  i++) {
            nums[i] = (i == zero_pos) ? product : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't made any attempt to deal with the risk of signed integer overflow in this code; that's as much a risk as it is in your original.

There are some problems in `fun2()`: failure to include `<string.h>` for the use of `memcpy()` is the most serious there.

We should use an unsigned type (probably `size_t`) for the size parameter.  That also means that we don't have mixed-signedness arithmetic where we multiply by `sizeof`.  Although having said that, we don't need to multiply - we can simply use `sizeof new_arr` (the whole array) and the compiler will manage that for us.

We can also reduce the scope of several of the variables:

```
#include <string.h>
void fun2(int *nums, int arr_size)
{
    int new_arr[arr_size];

    for (int i = 0;  i < arr_size;  i++) {
        int product = 1;
        for (int j = 0;  j < arr_size;  j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                product *= nums[j];
            }
        }
        new_arr[i]=product;
    }
    memcpy(nums, new_arr, sizeof new_arr);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Overflow**

Certainly the product of many `int` can overflow ---> leading to *udenfined bahavior* (UB).

If an additional specification included "the product does not overflow", we still have a problem with `fun()`.  That approach may overflow the *intermediate* product `sum`.

A work around is to use `long long` or `intmax_t` for `sum`.

Code could use a compile time check

```
#if LLONG_MAX/INT_MAX < INT_MAX
  #error "int lacks a 2x wide type."
#endif
```

**Zero**

A simple improvement would handle `num[i] == 0` and certainly not divide by zero.  If that occurs more than once, the resultant array is all zeros.  With only 1 `num[i] == 0`, all other elements are zero, and the one `i`  ellement is the product of the rest.

**C2x**

[C2X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x#Features) promotes the idiom of coding with the array size first.

```
// int fun(int* nums, int arr_size)
int fun(int arr_size, int* nums)
```

**`int` vs. `size_t`**

Array sizes may exceed `INT_MAX`.  Consider `size_t` for the size.  Keep in mind that `size_t` is an *unsigned* type.

**`int* nums` or `int *nums`**

C standard uses style `int *nums`.  Follow your group's style standard.

**Return value**

Perhaps use the return value for something useful.  Perhaps: detect overflow.

**Keep `for()` clean**

Avoid over-packing `for()`.  As with such coding style issue, follow group's standards.

```
// for(i=0, sum=1; i<arr_size; i++)
sum = 1;
for(i=0; i<arr_size; i++)
// of better, declare when needed
int sum = 1;
for(int i=0; i<arr_size; i++)
```

**Example**

*Unchecked code - will review later*

```
// Return NULL out-of-memory or overflow.
int fun(size_t arr_size, const int *nums) {
  int *parray = calloc(arr_size, sizeof *parray);
  if (parray == NULL) {
    return parray;
  }

  int *zero = NULL;
  intmax_t product = 1;
  bool overflow = false;
  
  for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
    if (nums[i]) {
      overflow |= mult_check(nums[i], &product);
    } else {
      if (zero) {
        return parray; // We are done, 2 zeros found
      }
      zero = &nums[i];
    }
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
    int divisor = nums[i] ? nums[i] : 1; 
    intmax_t q = product/divisor;
    if (q < INT_MIN || q > INT_MAX) {
      overflow = true;
      break;
    } 
  }

  if (overflow) {
    free(parray);
    return NULL;
  }

  return parray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your helpful responses. I am posting a better solution here with taking into consideration the suggestions of [Edward], [CiaPan], [chux], [superb rain] and others suggestions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//without division, with O(n) time, but extra space complexity as suggested
//return new array on the heap 
int *find_product_arr(const int *nums, int arr_size)
{
    int *new_arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*arr_size);

    int mult_prefix=1; //product of prefix elements
    int mult_suffix=1; //product of suffix elements
    
    //left most element special handling
    new_arr[0]=1;
    
    //swipe up 
    for(int i=1; i<arr_size; i++) {
        mult_prefix *= nums[i-1];
        new_arr[i] = mult_prefix;
    }
    
    //swipe down
    for(int j=arr_size-2; j>=0; j--) {
        mult_suffix *= nums[j+1];
        new_arr[j] *= mult_suffix;
    }
        
    return new_arr;
}


int main(void)
{
    /*Given an array of integers, return a new array such that each element at index i of the 
    new array is the product of all the numbers in the original array except the one at i.
    For example, if our input was [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], the expected output would be 
    [120, 60, 40, 30, 24] */
    int nums[] = {1, 2, 2, 4, 6};    
    int size = sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]);
    
    int *products = find_product_arr(nums, size); //get a new array
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        printf("%d ", *(products+i) ); 
    
    free(products); //release heap memory
   
    return 0;
}
```

It would be helpful if you give further improvements too.

Comment: You can create a follow up question by posting the new code in a new question and creating a link to this question. If you need an example of how [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/248817/common-unit-testing-code-follow-up?noredirect=1&lq=1) is one of my follow up questions.